# divide integer without remainder

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a set of numbers, where the total sum of them is always 1, I need to calculate the integer value that if divided on all those numbers the result will be without a remainder.

P.S: LCM won't work.

Any help?

Comment: This is about greatest common divisor rather than least common multiple.

Comment: GCD may be non integer, in my case I need an Integer

Comment: I don't follow your idea that the "GCD may be non integer". A common divisor of integers is an integer that divides them all.  The GCD is simply the largest of those integer divisors.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to assume "divided on" means "divided into". Suppose the sum of the numbers is $s$. If some integer $k$ divides each of the numbers without remainder then it must divide their sum without remainder too. So $s$ is a multiple of $k$. But we know $s=1$. So the only possible values for $k$ are $k= \pm 1$.

Comment: The question in other words, Integer/x should equal an integer, where x can be any number less or equal to 1. taking into consideration that I have not only x number, but multiple numbers their sum = 1

Ex: 0.25 , 0.5 and 0.25, in this case, 5 for example if divided on those numbers the result will be an integer without remainder.